# how to append text to its own div container without appending it to the other div container?

Tags: jquery, append, this

what the jquery code does below is it only clears the textbox

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var someText = $(".someText");
   
   $(".add").on("click", function(){
      $(".container", this).append(someText.val());
      $(someText).val("");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
     
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```

how do I append the text to its own container without being appended to the other?

Comment: FYI: (which no answers have yet mentioned) `$(".container", this)` is the equivalent of `$(this).find(".container")` - ie going the wrong way; down the DOM tree instead of up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are a bit broken – presumably you want each + to only append the value of its associated `.someText`. Is this what you had in mind?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".add").on("click", function(e){
      var container = $(this).closest(".container");
      var someText = $(".someText", container);

      container.append(someText.val());
      someText.val("");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
     
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$(this)` - your current selector is trying to find a container inside `this` but the container is the parent so you need to traverse up the tree, not down it.

Below I have switched out to use the event and it's current target `e.currentTarget` instead of `this`

```js
$(".add").on("click", e => {
  const $container = $(e.currentTarget).parent(); // get current container
  const $text = $container.find('.someText');     // get the text box

  $container.append($text.val());                 // append text to container
  $text.val("");                                  // clear input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest(".container")` to select a parent container (and not any of its siblings), see https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector

Also, to get the input text, make sure to select only the `<input>` next to the "+" control by using `siblings()`, see https://api.jquery.com/siblings/#siblings-selector

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(".add").on("click", function(){
      var $inp = $(this).siblings("input");
      $(this).closest(".container").append($inp.val());
      $inp.val("");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
     
<div class="container">
   <div class="add">+</div>
   <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery function **.closest()** to get the parent and then find the input text placed inside this parent. Like this, you will get only the target input and not all.

Try this code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").on("click", function(){
        let container = $(this).closest(".container")
        let someText = container.find(".someText");
        
        container.append(someText.val());
        someText.val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="add">+</div>
    <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
     
<div class="container">
    <div class="add">+</div>
    <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```