# how to append text to its own div container pt 2

Tags: jquery, text, append, containers

similiar to my question at [how to append text to its own div container without appending it to the other div container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995089/how-to-append-text-to-its-own-div-container-without-appending-it-to-the-other-di),
what would the jquery code look like if the html is something like this:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="addTextSection">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="addTextSection">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```

the text should be appended inside the `.container` not inside the `.addTextSection`

Comment: `$(".add").click(function() { $(this).closest(".addTextSection").prev().append($(this).text()) })`

Comment: @freedomn-m update: it only works on the first div container and when i click the button of the second div container it outputs the text that i typed in the inputbox of the first div container

Comment: In your original question, the `+` was inside the container, in this case the `+`'s parent is not inside the container, so you need .prev() - based on the HTML provided

Comment: Slight change to my comment above, as it's the input you want, so `this` is the button:  `$(this).next().val()`   https://jsfiddle.net/uqndpzcy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i in jquery there is **parent()** end **prev()** funtion with **parent()** you can select parent element then with **prev()** you can select previous dom so you can select your closest **.container** div then you can appent the input value my code is below.

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".add").on("click", function(){
            $(this).parent().prev(".container").append($(this).parent().find('.someText').val());
            $(this).parent().find('.someText').val("");
         });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="addTextSection">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="addTextSection">
  <div class="add">+</div>
  <input class="someText" type="text">
</div>
```